# Выбор директории с минимальным размером и вывод ее имени

Tags: python, windows, ос

требуется сканировать ряд директорий и вывести имя директории с самым маленьким размером
к примеру:
Несколько директорий, s1,s2,s3,s4,s5
Их размеры:
s1=1,s2=2,s3=3,s4=4,s5=5 (мб)
Нужно что бы программа вывела директорию s1, ибо ее размер меньше всего, 1мб
Это все нужно на питоне. Я уже научился сканировать размер директории, сейчас это выглядит так

```
import os


s1 = os.path.getsize('storage/s1')
s2 = os.path.getsize('storage/s2')
s3 = os.path.getsize('storage/s3')
s4 = os.path.getsize('storage/s4')
s5 = os.path.getsize('storage/s5')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directorys-size-using-python

Comment: Здорово, а вопрос в чём? Сейчас это выглядит, будто Вы поделились с нами Вашими успехами.

Comment: Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.